# how to bypass googletagmanager while scraping

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, beautifulsoup

When site added script googletagmanadger i cant get what I need. With this code I was scraping links from 
now Im getting "www.googletagmanager.com" in every row... So I dont know how to handle with that.Thank you

[HTML][1]

[HOW CSV FILE NOW LOOK][2]

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import pandas as pd
from csv import writer



data_list = ["LINKI", "GOWNO", "JAJCO"]

with open('innovators.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(data_list)
    for i in range(0,50):
        #df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Lukasz\\Desktop\\PROJEKTY PYTHON\\W TRAKCIE\\bf3_strona2.csv")
        #url = "https://bf3.space/" + df['LINKS'][i]
        url='https://bf3.space/a-Byu6am3P'
        response = requests.get(url)
        data = response.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
        rows = soup.find('iframe')
        q = (rows.get('src'))
        writer.writerow([q])


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ogq0N.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JYqc.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `soup.find()` with lambda.

For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://bf3.space/a-Byu6am3P'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

print( soup.find('iframe', src=lambda s: 'googletagmanager.com' not in s) )
```

Prints first non-googletagmanager `<iframe>` tag:

```
<iframe align="center" frameborder="0" height="1500" src="https://ven-way.x.yupoo.com/albums/83591895?uid=1" style="margin: 10px 0;padding: 0px 0px; border:none" width="100%"></iframe>
```